# What is the reference DLL need to be added for UserManager?

Tags: sitecore-client

```
ApplicationUser BuildUser(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
```

What is the reference DLL we need to add for this `UserManager` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sitecore, the `UserManager` class is part of the `Sitecore.Security.Accounts` namespace. To use it, you typically need to reference the `Sitecore.Kernel` assembly in your project. The DLL file you need is usually named `Sitecore.Kernel.dll`.

And if you are working on extending functionality make sure to add the `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication` DLL in your project.

As per your comments, make sure that you are referring to the following DLLs in your project to make the code working.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
```

Make sure to check the specific version of Sitecore you're working with, as the DLL version might vary.

Ensure that the DLLs are included in your project references, and you should be able to use the `UserManager` class for managing users in Sitecore.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Sumit, We already having the reference to this Sitecore.Kernel.dll. But still it is not showing in the suggestions.

Comment: What Sitecore version you are using?

Comment: It is Sitecore 10.2

Comment: I just trying to use the Code reference from here https://bala.one/sitecore-external-user-builder-azure-active-directory/

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Sumit for your help. I have reinstalled the Sitecore.Owin.Authentication nuget package with dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` class is part of the Microsoft ASP.NET Identity framework, and in the context of Sitecore, the `ApplicationUser` class is typically associated with Sitecore's Owin Authentication.

To use the `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` class, you should include the following reference DLLs in your project:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net48" />
```

Additionally, the `ApplicationUser` class is defined in the `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Identity` namespace, which is part of the `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication` package. Ensure you have the correct version installed, for example:

```
<package id="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" version="10.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
```

When installing the `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication` package, the installation process may automatically include the required dependencies. If you choose to install with the "Lowest dependency" behaviour, it should pull in `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`.

Alternatively, if you choose to `ignore` dependencies, you can manually install the specified versions of `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin`.

[image]